What are rollers that are sat one after one called?
How can I describe those rollers that are sat one after one? Does "a row of rollers" work?

The dough passes through a row of rollers.



"Rollers that are placed one after another".

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for highly domain-specific terminology that would be unknown to almost all native speakers

Side note:  to place something in a position or location is to set it there. They would be  set one after the other (not sat).

You forgot the step where the gasoline is rinsed out of the flour truck's tank before it is sent on the road. https://www.youtube.com/embed/b2w97JHBfEM

@TimR That use of sat is British English. Now, see, there we do have a difference in colloquial speech: He was sat by the door, for where we say: sitting. I like the question and the answer was quite clever. I'm sure FF can tell you all about sat for was sitting. It came up just other day on ELU, I think it was...

@Lambie Are you saying that BrE does not make a distinction between intransitive "sit" and transitive verb set , the latter verb meaning "to place something in a position or location"? It was sat on the mantel. Or are you saying OP meant "The rollers are sitting one after the other" not "The rollers are placed one after the other"?

@Lambie - That use of sat is British English - viewed by most Brits as non-standard and (by some) irritating.

I think that's a 'four-roller noodle press'.

In simple terms, you are labeling an existing series of rollers that flatten the dough into sheets. The assembly line is established; you are not instructing builders to set anything up anew. If calendar is the jargon you need, use that.

@MichaelHarvey I know all about that. Thanks.  "those rollers that are sat [=that are sitting] one after one?" Sure, non standard but heard often enough in Brit. police procedurals to know that it's that. There's also stood, for was standing.

@Lambie - ah, British police procedurals, those infallible guides to current English usage! I rather think they take the English language down the nick and give it a good kicking before verballing it up in front of the beak.

@Lambie - very often (mostly!) the dialogue on those shows is what a bunch of TV industry/BBC luvvies and their milieu think is how cops, crooks, etc, talk. With tweaks for the 'international' market.

@MichaelHarvey - I was recently called for jury service, and was astonished that not only police officers but even the judge referred to people being 'sat' or 'stood' somewhere! (As I've mentioned before, I'm one of those who find the usage irritating.)

@KateBunting - I spent my working life in the justice system, and saw a gradual change in the types of people who managed to be selected to be Crown & County Court judges. They aren't all white men who went to public schools any more, although the very highest levels still have a little way to go. Also the MoJ has been trying to make the justice system more 'accessible', and this includes language. I used to marvel at the solecisms I found in written judgements by Employment Tribunal judges.

@KateBunting - if you find 'I was sat', he was stood', etc, annoying, don't come to live in Bristol! Certain native Bristolians do all of them, and in particular they call someone who is horizontal 'laid down', and they pronounce the first word of that phrase 'led'.

@MichaelHarvey It is not just the cop shows. It's everywhere in English series when the speakers are not laddeedah. There's similar stuff in AmE. Why go on and on about this? I doubt very much that Brit. series writers sit around saying Ah, right, let's put in this or that expression for the "international audience". The same goes for American or Canadian or Australian or New Zealand (the main ones, eh?) writers. And as an American, I never say, Can I get the fish. to a server. I say: May I have the fish. I guess that makes me posh, for a gringa.

A calender is a series of rollers used to process paper, rubber, or other materials that form thin sheets. The verb to calender refers to the process of passing through a calender.
(Not to be confused with a calendar, a system or table for organizing the days of a week, month, or year.)
Wikipedia has a page Calender which says:

A calender is a series of hard pressure rollers used to finish or smooth a sheet of material such as paper, textiles, rubber, or plastics. Calender rolls are also used to form some types of plastic films and to apply coatings.


The word "calender" itself is a derivation of the word κύλινδρος kylindros, the Greek word that is also the source of the word "cylinder".

You can also find verb and noun in good dictionaries such as Merriam-Webster.

(verb) to press (cloth, rubber, paper, etc.) between rollers or plates in order to smooth and glaze or to thin into sheets


(noun) a machine for calendering something


This is the kind of answer that merits many upvotes. This often happens to me. I find the right answer like you did, and no one upvotes or they even dv. I cannot figure it out unless it's due to undue competition (haha). +1

I did not know this word, (though I have heard of super-calendered paper). I suspect that few English speakers know it, unless they work in a relevant industry.

I also feel the word is too advanced for English learners. What about "a series of rollers"?

I don't know that any word should be called too advanced for learners if it is the only suitable word.  It is probably best to alert the learner to the fact that the word will only be understood or used by those who are familiar with the details of the associated industry, noodle making in this example.  But if the learner actually works in that industry or is reporting on that industry, then they should certainly be made aware of the word.  Knowing which word to use and when is part of ELLing.

I don't think industrial calender machines are applicable for such delicate fresh pasta or any  type of dough come to think of it. I feel the pressure exerted on the pasta would stretch the flat layers of dough so thinly it would inevitably break. The OP's diagram shows a short series of rollers, nothing more nor less.

@Mari-LouA the rollers almost certainly have a thickness setting, rather than squashing something soft out of existence.

@WeatherVane  I don't see how that type of machinery being used by Barilla. The spaghetti (aka noodles) are stretched not squashed by rollers. Maybe hot pot noodles is a completely different thing.

@Mari-LouA I dunno, machines with rollers are machines with rollers. Does the industry matter in that sense? The mechanics are the same regardless of what is being made: sheets of steel, or whatever.
